# Translating jquery idiom to YUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

How can I translate the following jquery idiom to YUI?

```
$("a").click(function(event){
     alert("Saw a click!");
   });
```

The above is supposed to add a custom on-click event to all anchor tags in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use event delegation

YUI 3*

```
Y.delegate('click', function (e) {
    alert("Click received");
}, document, 'a');
```

or

```
Y.get(document).delegate('click',fn, 'a');
```

YUI 2

```
YAHOO.util.Event.on(document,'click',function (e) {
    var target = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);
    if (target.nodeName && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        alert("Click received");
    }
});
```

- the YUI 3 beta release has a bug in delegate that prevents document listeners from working.  This is fixed for the upcoming GA release.

Answer (score 5):

YUI 3

```
Y.all('li').on('click', function() {
        alert('Clickety-click!');
    });
```

YUI 2

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(lis, 'click', function() {
        alert('Clickety-click!');
    });
```

Answers from: 
[Translate the following jQuery code to YUI 2.x code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813523/translate-the-following-jquery-code-to-yui-2-x-code)

Also: YUI 3 will support chaining operations, until then use the dedchain library from dechain.dustindiaz.com

Comment: Your YUI2 example can be smaller if you remove the intermediate "lis" variable.